# Google Test/Mock Unit testing c++ - How to mock interface which has method with pointer?

Tags: unit-testing

I have an interface as follows:

```
class {
virtual bool display(char* name) = 0;
};
```

I have mocked this interface and during test I have added expect_call as follows:

```
    char* name = "name";
    EXPECT_CALL(mockHandler, display(testing::_))
         .WillOnce(testing::DoAll(testing::SetArgPointee<0>(data),         testing::Return(ErrorState::SERIAL_PORT_SUCCESS)));
```

But it is not working as expected. Any help would be really appreciated.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: please refer SetArrayArgument<0>(values, values + 5) at http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html

Answer (score 0):

Refering code from http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_cook_book.html could fix the issue. I was not giving arguments correctly to
.WillOnce(SetArrayArgument<0>(values, values + 5))